# SQL query:Is this query right? Better way to write it?

Tags: sql

Users(**uid**, name, birthday, country)
Events(**eid**, name, uid, date)
Guests (**eid**, **uid**, status)

I need to find the people who made events on the same time user uid=123 made events. Is there any more elegant way to do that then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT U1.uid, U1.name
FROM Users U1, Events E1, Events E
WHERE E.uid=123 AND E1.uid<>123 AND E1.date=E.date AND  U1.uid=E1.uid
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should stop using the out-dated implicit joins and use explicit `JOIN`s instead

Comment: What is the relevance of the `guests` table ?

Answer (score 2):

You can restate your query as follows:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM Users U WHERE uid <> 123 AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Events E WHERE uid = U.uid AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM Events WHERE date = E.date AND uid = 123
    )
)
```

Note that you don't need `DISTINCT`, because there are no `JOIN`s threatening to induce redundant rows.

While this is logically the cleanest way to express the query, your SQL optimiser might not forgive you for the doubly-nested `SELECT`s. If so, you can unroll the innermost `SELECT`s into a `JOIN`. It isn't quite as clean, but it will accomplish the same effect.

If that still doesn't yield acceptable performance, then you may be stuck with your original three-way join.

Comment: @wildplasser: The OQ selects distinct `uid`/`name` from Users (The `DISTINCT` makes the presence of joined tables irrelevant). Mine selects non-distinct `uid`/`name` from Users and has no joins. These could only produce different results if `{uid, name}` isn't a superkey. Since `uid` is almost certainly the primary key, this seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

when we use distinct with multiple column and varchar column it will result into slower query performance . you can do something like following:

```
SELECT U1.uid, U1.name
FROM Users U1 I
INNER JOIN  
(
SELECT DISTINCT E1.UID 
FROM Events E1 INNER JOIN Events E ON E.uid = 123 AND E1.uid <> 123 AND E1.date = E.date
) AS A
WHERE 
U1.uid = A.uid
```

Comment: was this ans help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Using distinct as a means to remove duplicate results should be avoided as it is very inefficient.  It works by taking a list of results with duplicates and then removing those duplicates.  You should always attempt to design a query to not return the duplicate results in the first place.

This query should return the results you're looking for without duplication.

```
Select U.UID,U.Name
From Events E
Inner Join Events E1 on E1.uid<>E.uid and E1.Date=E.Date
Inner Join Users U on U.UID = E1.UID
Where E.UID=123
```

Comment: The OP wants users in the result, not events.